# How to unwrap an Optional value?

Tags: swift3, xcode7, option-type, uint32, uint

So I have this in my code.

```
let hex:String = "#FFFFFF"
var returnValue = UInt()
var newString = String()

newString = hex.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "0x")
returnValue = UInt(newString)! //This line gets an error
```

It gives me an unwrapping optional value error. How do I fix it?

Comment: Swift 3 Xcode version is 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong initializer and even if it was the right initializer the string format is wrong:

```
let hex = "#FFFFFF"
let newString = hex.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
let returnValue = UInt(newString, radix:16) ?? 0
```